# Can I use JPA/EJB3 on a table that was created at runtime?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, ejb-3.0

This is weird and probably not possible but I'll ask anyway.  I'm making this app that reads in a meta file and creates some tables then populates them with data.  I was wondering if I could somehow use JPA to populate those tables.  Obviously, there's no way I could have an entity with annotations on it since the table didn't exist at compile time.  But perhaps JPA or the entity manager has a way to load data into a table that without an entity class?

If possible, I'd expect a method like

```
entityManager.update("myTableName", hashMapOfColumnNamesAndColumnDataValues);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe use a native SQL query. Have a look at the `EntityManager#createNativeQuery` methods.

Comment: Yes, I probably could but that has all the downsides i'm trying to avoid: It's not db independent, I've gotta write the sql by hand, etc. etc.

Comment: @tieTYT I understand but I'm not aware of something close to what you mentioned and I don't know any easy way to construct classes dynamically and to register them. In other words, I don't have any better suggestion.